# webpack2, react, babel: production source maps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, source-maps

I'm on the latest webpack2 and trying to generate source-maps for a react application. Features i'm using in webpack:

- jsx
- es6
- minification using uglifyjs

I've read the docs here https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/
and experimented some based on the reference link provided here: http://cheng.logdown.com/posts/2016/03/25/679045

For the production-type source maps (where the sourcemap is in a file separate from the bundled code) nothing except the base *source-map* value works.

By works I mean when an error occurs i do not get the correct line number of the error location in the original source.

ideally i'd like to use cheap-source-map or cheap-module-source-map to avoid including original source in the source-map.

Has anyone gotten this to work?